# Is Xlib Still Used?

Tags: xlib

Is xlib still used? The helpful documentation I can find is http://tronche.com/ which looks, to me, very outdated. Who uses Xlib? Is GTK+ and QT built on it? thanks in advance, ell.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472540/creating-a-window-manager-for-linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, toolkits like GTK+ and Qt are still built on Xlib.   Migration to [xcb](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/) is in progress, but far from complete or universal.   Applications though really should be writing to the toolkit API's, not Xlib.

BTW, you can also find Xlib docs directly from the source at X.Org: http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/

Answer (score 3):

These days, [libxcb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCB) is used. There is also an xlib compatibility layer still available (xlib-xcb).

Answer (score 3):

Well if you want hardware acceleration, according to freedesktop.org:

[an OpenGL application on the X Windows must use Xlib and thus can’t be done using only XCB.](http://xcb.freedesktop.org/opengl/#index2h1)

You have to have xlib even if you're only using xcb if you want opengl.